# Connect to broadband from command line- Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, broadband

How do I connect to a Broadband Connection from the command prompt in Windows 7?

Comment: Try C:\>netsh wlan connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you had an available broadband connection, rasdial is the command to dail an existing connection.

For example, to dial to a **connection name** is **bc**, **user name** is **user**, **password** is **pass**:

> rasdial bc user pass

Comment: Thanks. `rasdial` had been showing me error all this time, not for now.